Client request Java threadpool
I'm developing a Java server-client application where the server handles multiple clients using a thread pool and Java NIO's Selector. Each client can request various actions such as login, registration, etc. When a client makes a request, like "login" or "register," the server must send a prompt, such as "Enter username" or "Enter city," and then wait for the client's response before proceeding (all through the terminal)
In this setup, each client request is assigned to a thread from the thread pool. However, there are scenarios where a thread needs to wait for the client's response after sending a prompt. During this waiting period, the response should not be processed by the selector as a new request. Instead, it should be handled by the same thread from the thread pool that is currently managing the client. This ensures that the thread pool thread remains responsible for both sending prompts and processing responses, rather than creating a new task or having the selector handle the client's response.
I have associated an object with each SocketChannel that contains a state. When the thread is waiting for a response from the client, it sets this state to WAITING. This way, when the Selector reads the state, it knows not to handle the request itself but to let the thread that is already associated with the SocketChannel handle it. However, I'm not sure how to ensure that the thread handles the request directly and not the Selector. Alternatively, removing the channel from the Selector's monitoring list might be an option, but I don't think it's ideal because I might have to do this frequently.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
